# Adding existing solution to TFS source control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, web-config

I'm trying to add existing solution to source control in TFS 2012.

While trying to checkin(add) whole solution I get bunch of errors saying that it Could not find file like .config .gif .datasource .xsd.

Solution is quite big - over 100 projects, removing or undoing changes for all those files from source control will be messy. Moreover I'm not sure if removing them from source control wont break whole solution.

Is there any way to avoid that kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is mainly caused when you're trying to check in files which is no longer exist on the machine.

To remove these changes from the list, you can either delete the nonexistent files from solution explorer, or go to **Source Control Explorer** -> select these missing files -> **Undo Pending Changes**. Or you can just left these files in the **Excluded Changes** list to not checking them.

Comment: How does one "Delete the nonexistent files"? :-)

Comment: @ToreØstergaard, I mean the files may have been deleted on local machine, but they still appear in solution explorer, so remove them from solution explorer then check in the solution. :-)